# How to decode a QRCode in java?I use ZXing and QRCode,but sometimes they do not work

Tags: java, zxing

The method used ZXing to decode the image:

```
public static String decode(BufferedImage image) {
    try {
        if (image == null) {
            System.out.println("bufferedImage is null");
            return null;
        }
        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Result result;
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");
        result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap, hints);
        String resultStr = result.getText();
        //System.out.println("the qrcode str: " + resultStr);
        return resultStr;
    } catch (com.google.zxing.NotFoundException re) {
        //System.out.println("no str in the image");
        return null;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```

and Use QRcode.jar:

```
    public static String decodeUseQRcode(BufferedImage image){
        QRCodeDecoder decoder = new QRCodeDecoder();
        String content = null;
        try {
            content = new String(decoder.decode(new TwoDimensionCodeImage(image)),"gbk");
        } catch (DecodingFailedException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return content;
    }
```

the picture can't be decoded by QRCode.jar and ZXing,the results are all "null".Seem  the two java method can not decode the picture.

but I use WeChat and other app can decode this .
how to increase the rate of decoding the picture successfully?
(i don't have 10 reputation ,so i can not post image.Both two method works sometimes.but not always work.)
The link of the picture. http://postimg.org/image/s6tpzv1gf/

Comment: Post a link to the picture.

Comment: @NathanTuggy the link of the picture.  http://postimg.org/image/s6tpzv1gf/